# Multiply pandas dataframe with factor from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The columns of a multi-index data frame, say,

```
df_multi = pd.DataFrame({'angles': [0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6],
                 'degrees': [360, 180, 360, 360, 540, 720]},
                index=[['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                       ['circle', 'triangle', 'rectangle',
                        'square', 'pentagon', 'hexagon']])
df_scale = pd.DataFrame({'factor': [0,1]},index = ['A','B'])
```

```
             angles  degrees
A circle          0      360
  triangle        3      180
  rectangle       4      360
B square          4      360
  pentagon        5      540
  hexagon         6      720

   factor
A       0
B       1
```

should be multiplied by a scaling factor from another data frame where the indices on a given level match.
I tried

```
df_scale.mul(df_multi, level = 0, axis = 'index')
```

but this does produce three columns with NaN values, instead of

```
             angles  degrees
A circle          0        0
  triangle        0        0
  rectangle       0        0
B square          4      360
  pentagon        5      540
  hexagon         6      720
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
x = df_multi.mul(df_scale["factor"], level=0, axis="index")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
             angles  degrees
A circle          0        0
  triangle        0        0
  rectangle       0        0
B square          4      360
  pentagon        5      540
  hexagon         6      720
```